# Swift 3 TableViewController does not deinit

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory-management, deinit

My Swift 3 iOS App Starts with a LoginViewController, which segues to a TabBarController, which has 3 ChildViews, each one is a NavigationController being the rootView to a ViewController.

One ViewController contains a Logout Button, which performs an unwindSegue to the LoginViewController.

The other one (this one is critical) has 2 container views, one of them is a TableViewController. The TableViewController is filled dynamically with data from the backend.

When the backend gives me 0 data, everything works fine. You can press on the Logout Button and every ViewController, as well as the ContainerViews and the TableView gets deinit() correctly.

**As soon as the TableViewController gets data from the backend and displays cells, it does no longer call deinit() for the TableViewController**.

What might the cause be? I can share code on request.

**what i have tried so far:**
I tried to use unowned self everywhere a closure exists. Now i am unsure for this part where i get the data with the @escaping:

```
func loadMyMessages()
{
let myMessagesURL = "https://www.thewebsite.com/rest/messages/mine"
self.tableView.isHidden = true
if let url = URL(string: myMessagesURL) {
    self.updateFeedFilter(url, filter: self.activeFilter, hashTag: activeHashTags, completion: {  [unowned self] (feed) -> Void in
        self.feed?.items.removeAll()
        self.feed = feed
    })
}
}

func updateFeedFilter(_ url: URL, filter: String, hashTag: String, completion:   @escaping  (_ feed: Feed?) -> Void) {
let sid = self.prefs.string(forKey: "sid")
let headers2: HTTPHeaders = [
    "lastId": "0",
    "sid": sid!,
    "filter": filter,
    "hashTags": hashTag
]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers2)
    .responseJSON { [unowned self] response in
        print(response)
        guard let responseError = response.result.error else {
            let feed = Feed(data: response.data!, sourceURL: url)
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
                completion(feed)
                self.scrollToFirstRow()
                self.tableView.isHidden = false
                self.delegateClicked?.stopIndicator()
            })
            return
        }
        self.showNoInternetDialog()
        self.delegateClicked?.stopIndicator()
    }
}
```

I am thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: In general - you have to check the issue of strong reference cycle, it can be caused by closures or by releshenships of other reference type objects.

Comment: that is what i checked first. i made all my delegates weak var, and all my closures unowned. i am not sure for the escaping closure which is shown in the code example. Could it be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out. I had to use [unowned self] inside a closure where i defined the action for hashTagTapped, which is provided by the ActiveLabel pod.

For closures try to use [unowned self], for delegates try to use weak var.